# Manipulating data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df with one of the columns called Rule_ID. It has data like -

```
Rule_ID
[u'2c78g',u'df567',u'5ty78']
[u'2c78g',u'd67gh',u'df890o']
[u'd67gh',u'df890o',u'5ty78']
[u'2c78g',u'5ty78',u'df890o']
```

I want to count all unique rule ID's within the column and create a new data frame df1 with two columns, first one containing the unique rule ID and the second one containing the count of that ID. For example in above case df1 would contain -

```
Rule_ID     Count
u'2c78g'    3
u'df567'    1
u'5ty78'    3
u'd67gh'    2
u'df890o'   3
```

Comment: Attempt at a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
df.Rule_ID.apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()

df890o    3
5ty78     3
2c78g     3
d67gh     2
df567     1
dtype: int64
```

---

**Option 2**

```
pd.value_counts(pd.np.concatenate(df.Rule_ID.values))

df890o    3
5ty78     3
2c78g     3
d67gh     2
df567     1
dtype: int64
```

---

If those are strings, do this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

pd.value_counts(pd.np.concatenate([literal_eval(x) for x in df.Rule_ID.values]))
# or
# df.Rule_ID.apply(literal_eval).apply(pd.Series).stack().value_counts()

df890o    3
5ty78     3
2c78g     3
d67gh     2
df567     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: TypeError: unbound method nunique() must be called with Series instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: @Dreamer it should be fixed now.

Comment: It is giving me results like - ['df890o','5ty78','2c78g'] 3, because all these three IDs have the same count. Can you break it ? As in only one Rule ID in each cell with its corresponding count next to it. Thank you so much! You have always been so helpful

Comment: That's unfortunate... its because the values are strings that look like lists.

Comment: :( What is the solution?

Comment: Option 2 doesn't seem to be working for me. Option 1 is working. Is there a possible solution using Option 1?

Comment: @Dreamer updated again.  All options should work now.  I assumed you had imported `numpy`.  That was my fault for making the assumption.  You don't need to though,  `pandas` already does.  So i changed `np` to `pd.np`.  Saves you the import but costs you three characters to type.

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot. I am wondering if there was a location column in the initial question. How would have you approached this same problem? As in give the count of each Rule ID specific to location. I would really want to see your solution for this. Really impressed with how you approach the problem.

Comment: You use `groupby`... this sounds like an excellent question to post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786462/manipulating-data-frames-based-on-different-columns . Here you go! Would love to see your approach.