# Manipulating data frames based on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df with two columns called Rule_ID and Location. It has data like -

```
Rule_ID                         Location
[u'2c78g',u'df567',u'5ty78']    US
[u'2c78g',u'd67gh',u'df890o']   India
[u'd67gh',u'df890o',u'5ty78']   Japan
[u'2c78g',u'5ty78',u'df890o']   US
```

I want two results. One count of unique rule ids of each location. Here it should look like -

```
Location    Count_of_unique_rule_ids
US          4
India       3
Japan       3
```

Second I want count of rule_ids as per location. Here it would look like -

```
Rule_ID    Count   Location
u'2c78g'   2       US
u'df567'   1       US 
u'5ty78'   2       US
```

and so on!

This is an extension to the question here - [Manipulating data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784358/manipulating-data-frames/44785322?noredirect=1#comment76553091_44785322)

Comment: @piRSquared Would love to see your approach.

Comment: Psidom's answer is what I would have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way

Using `apply`

```
In [235]: df.groupby('Location')['Rule_ID'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x.sum())))
Out[235]:
Location
India    3
Japan    3
US       4
Name: Rule_ID, dtype: int64
```

-

```
In [236]: (df.groupby('Location')
             .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Rule_ID'].sum()))
             .reset_index()
             .groupby(['Location', 0]).size())
Out[236]:
Location  0
India     2c78g     1
          d67gh     1
          df890o    1
Japan     5ty78     1
          d67gh     1
          df890o    1
US        2c78g     2
          5ty78     2
          df567     1
          df890o    1
dtype: int64
```

---

**Details**

`x.sum()` on list joins them, you could get unique count by counting set of the list.

```
In [237]: df.groupby('Location')['Rule_ID'].apply(lambda x: x.sum())
Out[237]:
Location
India                         [2c78g, d67gh, df890o]
Japan                         [d67gh, df890o, 5ty78]
US       [2c78g, df567, 5ty78, 2c78g, 5ty78, df890o]
Name: Rule_ID, dtype: object
```

Applying `pd.Series` on list would create new rows, then `groupby` on location and measure.

```
In [240]: df.groupby('Location').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Rule_ID'].sum()))
Out[240]:
Location
India     0     2c78g
          1     d67gh
          2    df890o
Japan     0     d67gh
          1    df890o
          2     5ty78
US        0     2c78g
          1     df567
          2     5ty78
          3     2c78g
          4     5ty78
          5    df890o
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your data frame to long format (unnest column *Rule_ID*), after which it would be straight forward to summarize:

```
df_long = pd.DataFrame({
        "Rule_ID": [e for s in df.Rule_ID for e in s],
        "Location": df.Location.repeat(df.Rule_ID.str.len())
    })

df_long.groupby('Location').Rule_ID.nunique()

#Location
#India    3
#Japan    3
#US       4
#Name: Rule_ID, dtype: int64

df_long.groupby(['Rule_ID', 'Location']).size()

#Rule_ID    Location
#u'2c78g'   India       1
#           US          2
#u'5ty78'   Japan       1
#           US          2
#u'd67gh'   India       1
#           Japan       1
#u'df567'   US          1
#u'df890o'  India       1
#           Japan       1
#           US          1
#dtype: int64
```